# Python Mechanize: How to input into TextControl and click on ImageControl icon?

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to enter postal code information into http://www.gasbuddy.com/ and click 'Search' using Mechanize

So I was able to scrape the form with the following data:

```
<TextControl(ctl00$Content$GBZS$txtZip=City, Province or Postal Code...)>
<ImageControl(ctl00$Content$GBZS$btnSearch=)>
```

I am able to insert text into the TextControl (I assume), which changes the form to:

```
<TextControl(ctl00$Content$GBZS$txtZip=ABC 123)>
<ImageControl(ctl00$Content$GBZS$btnSearch=)>
```

using the following code:

```
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser["ctl00$Content$GBZS$txtZip"] = "ABC 123"

for form in browser.forms():
    print list(browser.forms())[0];
```

So my question is how can I click the ImageControl? I tried doing a browser.submit(), but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

The form cannot be submitted by `mechanize`:

- there is not `submit` button at all
- there is javascript involved in the clicking on the image control:

  ```
  <input type="image" name="ctl00$Content$GBZS$btnSearch" id="ctl00_Content_GBZS_btnSearch" class="zs_img" src="/images/art/search-84x23-bt.png" alt="Gas Price Search" 
   onclick="javascript:if(btnSearch_click(event) == false){return false;};WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$Content$GBZS$btnSearch&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;, &quot;Search.aspx&quot;, false, false))" style="border-width:0px;">
  ```

Here's what you can do:

- simply get the page which is opened after the search - just paste the city name inside the url. For example, for the `New York City` the url is: http://www.newyorkgasprices.com/New%20York%20City/index.aspx

  ```
  import mechanize
  from urllib2 import quote

  url = "http://www.newyorkgasprices.com/%s/index.aspx"
  city = "New York City"
  url = url % quote(url)

  browser = mechanize.Browser()
  browser.open(url)

  browser.title()
  ```
- use a real browser with [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get('http://www.gasbuddy.com/')

  city = 'New York City'

  textinput = browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Content_GBZS_txtZip')
  textinput.send_keys(city)

  button = browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_Content_GBZS_btnSearch')
  button.click()

  print browser.title

  browser.close()
  ```

Both snippets print:

```
'New York City Gas Prices - Find Cheap Gas Prices in New York City, New York'
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine beautifulSoup with selenium webdriver to scrap the page and return results? All running through the browser?

Comment: @user1607549 `selenium` itself is pretty powerful in [locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html).